# ¿Qué significa "superajustada"?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, significado

According to http://www.translate.com/, the translation of "superajustada" in to English is  "superajustada" - that's helpful! (not!)

It gives for "ajustada" adjusted, so...superadjusted? What does that mean/Que significa eso?

Comment: https://translate.google.com/#es/en/super%20ajustada

Comment: Very interesting; the way I saw it written, it was "one word". There on google translate, as two words it gives "super tight," as one word it reflects back the same (as the first one I tried) and "ajustada" alone was "adjusted"

Comment: it's one word, but you have to help a little to google, he is not a spanish speaker :) `@query = SELECT (prefix+space(1)+word) AS translation FROM Spanish`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Super" is a prefix that means "very" and "ajustada" means tight in its feminine form.

So it means "very tight".

Answer (score 4):

En España se utiliza cuando se habla con alguien para referirse a una persona del género femenino que lleva la ropa muy apretada o pegada a la piel.

Comment: También en México. Otra forma es super entallada o entallada.

Answer (score 3):

El término super ajustada en español es un adjetivo calificativo que modifica al sustantivo y se utiliza generalmente cuando una persona tiene poco dinero, es un término a la moda, en Argentina.